# s2013 multi device hybrid apps and deploy to both android emulator and device

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Iam tring to run in Vs2013 multi device hybrid apps and deploy to both android emulator and device.  But keep getting the following errors.

I have added the apk and modified the environment settings. Also created an emulutor in the avd manger

Error  14  G:\Developement\WindowsPhone\Wp8Test\test20\test20\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126  test20
Error   15  throw e;    test20
Error   16  ^   test20
Error   17  ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found. test20

Comment: If you do have a device, please make sure the right device drivers are installed on your PC so the MDHA tooling can recognize the device.

Answer (score 2):

The error appears when you do not have the right set of drivers for your device installed on the machine.

To fix this, visit:

- [Device-specific OEM driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html), or
- [Google USB driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top) for Google Nexus devices

Once that is done, ensure that you go to Device Manager in Settings and update the drivers for your device by pointing to the location of the download.

Once done, you should be able to deploy to device seamlessly.

Note: Choose Allow USB Debugging if prompted on your Android device.

*Taken from the official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757059.aspx).